# How to log using one formatter to file and using colored formatter to terminal?

Tags: python

I wish to log to file as well as show the same information in the terminal window, but with nice colors (using [colorlog](https://github.com/borntyping/python-colorlog) or other cross-platform log colorizer). This is what I have:

```
import logging
import os

import colorlog


def logger(log_filepath='my_app.log', logger_name='myAppLogger'):
    """Log plain text to file and to terminal with colors"""

    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)

    # Log to file (but not to terminal)
    logfile_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_filepath)
    plain_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    logfile_handler.setFormatter(plain_formatter)
    logfile_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # Logging info level to stdout with colors
    terminal_handler = colorlog.StreamHandler()
    color_formatter = colorlog.ColoredFormatter(
        "%(log_color)s%(levelname)-8s%(reset)s %(asctime)s %(blue)s%(message)s",
        datefmt=None,
        reset=True,
        log_colors={
            'DEBUG':    'cyan',
            'INFO':     'green',
            'WARNING':  'yellow',
            'ERROR':    'red',
            'CRITICAL': 'red,bg_white',
        },
        secondary_log_colors={},
        style='%'
    )
    terminal_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    terminal_handler.setFormatter(color_formatter)

    # Add handlers to logger
    logger.addHandler(logfile_handler)
    logger.addHandler(terminal_handler)

    return logger


my_logger = logger()

my_logger.debug('Testing debug')
my_logger.info('Testing info')
my_logger.warning('Testing warning')
my_logger.error('Testing error')
my_logger.critical('Testing critical')
```

This gives me the following in the terminal (with colors):

```
WARNING  2017-01-23 20:30:55,180 Testing warning
ERROR    2017-01-23 20:30:55,180 Testing error
CRITICAL 2017-01-23 20:30:55,181 Testing critical
```

...and this in the log file (no colors, just plain text):

```
2017-01-23 20:30:55,180 WARNING Testing warning
2017-01-23 20:30:55,180 ERROR Testing error
2017-01-23 20:30:55,181 CRITICAL Testing critical
```

Why is the level not right though?

Comment: Why is `logfile_handler` using `color_formatter` and not `terminal_handler`?

Comment: Thanks - that was it. But what about the level? (updated the question)

Comment: As for the level, you need to set `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` instead of `terminal_handler.setLevel...`. I've got an idea why this might be the case but I'll confirm and then post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your (original) code. The first was a minor error in which you assigned `color_formatter` to the log handler instead of the terminal handler.

The second issue - that you weren't seeing logs below `WARNING` level in your terminal - was caused by the fact that you were setting the minimum logging level on the terminal *handler* but not the *logger itself*. You need to replace:

```
terminal_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

With:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html), loggers are set to `WARNING` log level by default, and if my intuition is correct then setting only the handler to a lower log level would not work because the handler can only process what the logger feeds it anyway - `WARNING`-level logs and above.